# С++ Регулярные выражения. Рекурсия?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, имею задачу получить список содержимого между пар (...) скобок в любом выражении. Т.е например: ( тест1(тест2(тест3)). В данном примере я должен получить выражения тест2(тест3) и тест3, но не получить тест1, т.к нет соответствующей закрывающей скобки. (аналогично должно быть и с открывающими, если нет пары, выражение игнорируется.) **Если я правильно понял, конечно**.

**Задание дословно:**

1)проверить, правильно ли в тексте расставлены круглые кобки(т.е находится ли правее каждой открывающейся скобки закрывающаяся и левее закрывающейся - открывающаяся) 
2) вывести содержимое правильно проставленных скобок в виде списка.

На данный момент составил что-то вроде этого: ((?:[^()]+|\g<2>*)) [ссылка на regex101 для удобства](https://regex101.com/r/FroWH7/1). Но я делаю что-то не так, вроде тут нужно использовать рекурсию, но я не могу понять как. Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FroWH7/2 - минимальные правки, чтобы Ваш пример был рабочим. https://regex101.com/r/FroWH7/3 правильный вариант решения. Ответ писать не хочу, ибо рекурсия в регулярных выражениях- это самая обычная рекурсия, хоть это довольно непросто сразу осознать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, все куда проще...
Например, для №1 просто идете по порядку, для каждой открывающейся скобки прибавляете 1, для закрывающей - вычитаете... И следите, не опустится ли сумма ниже нуля :)

Что от вас хотят в №2 - я что-то не очень понял. Поясните подробнее - уверен, и тут регулярные выражения ни при чем...

Comment: Нужно получить содержимое между 'успешных' скобок, я так понимаю. Есть еще мысль, что пункт 2, только для варианта, когда у каждой открывающей скобки, есть пара закрывающей

Comment: Опять же, вносите в стек позиции открывающих скобок, встречая закрывающую - просто выводите все, что находится от соответствующей сохраненной позиции до текущей...

Comment: хм... попробую, спасибо, мне кажется должно сработать